# Open Xml: Word Create a new Document and add a paragraph from another document

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a document that I am iterating thru getting the paragraphs. For each of these paragraphs I need to create a new document and save it. I can't figure out how to add a Paragraph from the source document to the new one.

```
        foreach (var p in paragraphsFromSourceDocument)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memoryStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                doc.AddMainDocumentPart();

                // Create the Document DOM. 
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();

                //Add the paragraph 'p' to the Body here:
                // HOW ?????????

                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 // Open the file read-only since we don't need to change it.
        using (var wordprocessingDocument =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFileName, true))
        {
            paragraphs = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                .OfType<Paragraph>().ToList();
            styles = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

            foreach (var p in paragraphs)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memoryStream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
                    doc.AddMainDocumentPart().AddPart(styles);
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(p.CloneNode(true));
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                    Console.WriteLine(GetHTMLOfDoc(doc));

                }
            }
        }
```